# An injective map $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^{f(n)}\ln\frac{f(n)+1}{f(n)}=\ln2017. $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I'm having trouble with this qustion. please help if you can:

prove that there exists an $f:N \to N$ that is injective and $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty (-1)^{f(n)}\ln\frac{f(n)+1}{f(n)}=\ln2017$

and here's the hard part, without finding f(just to prove the existence of such function).

i basically tried to check how to converges when f(n) is odd, even, n^2 in order to find a definition for f(n), however i did not find anything. i also tried to use the fact it converges to ln2017 and the fact that it's injective(from what i understand, since it's injective, $(-1)^{f(n)}$ must be odd, because we don't want them to be even(else it won't be injective)). anyways i'm totally lost, is there a nice way to calculate it without finding f? please help if you can.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use the following result we don't have to worry about the $(-1)^{f(n)}$ business.

Thm: Suppose $a_n$ is a nonnegative sequence such that $a_n\to 0$ and $\sum a_n = \infty$. Then given $x>0,$ there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $\sum_k a_{n_k} = x.$ The proof of this is similar to the proof of Riemann's rearrangement theorem for conditionally convergent series, except it's easier.

Now $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln \frac{2n+1}{2n}$ diverges, and the terms $\to 0.$ Thus by the theorem there is a subsequence $n_k$ such that

$$\tag 1 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ln \frac{2n_k+1}{2n_k} = \ln 2017.$$

Define the injection $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ by $f(k) = 2n_k.$ Since $f(k)$ is even for all $k,$ $(-1)^{f(k)} = 1$ for all $k.$ Thus the series in $(1)$ is precisely the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{f(k)}\ln \frac{f(k)+1}{f(k)}$$

and we're done.

Comment: thank you very much. i'll study your answer and the thorem